# I'm getting an error TS1109: Expression expected in angular project im working on

Tags: angular

i was following this https://developers.google.com/codelabs/building-a-web-app-with-angular-and-firebase#4 tutorial, and im getting the error on line 11 : todo: Task[] = [...];
in the tutorial it don't say anything about this error, and i am stuck.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from './task/task';
import { CdkDragDrop, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  todo: Task[] = [...];
  inProgress: Task[] = [];
  done: Task[] = [];

  editTask(list: string, task: Task): void {}

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Task[]>): void {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      return;
    }
    if (!event.container.data || !event.previousContainer.data) {
      return;
    }
    transferArrayItem(
      event.previousContainer.data,
      event.container.data,
      event.previousIndex,
      event.currentIndex
    );
  }
}
```

i have tried to check and update the typescript version but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

`todo: Task[] = [...]` is not valid syntax.

It should either be `[]` or a valid array of `Task` objects (which is potentially what the tutorial was hinting at). Just by looking at the code though, I would be tempted to say that `todo: Task[] = []` is more appropriate

Comment: yeah i just found the github of that tutorial, and i thought those 3 dots are spread operator but it actually ment that i need to putt some hard coded data inside the array. my bad. but thank you anyway :)

Comment: No problem, glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should add data of array from previous lesson
https://developers.google.com/codelabs/building-a-web-app-with-angular-and-firebase#3

```
todo: Task[] = [
    {
      title: 'Buy milk',
      description: 'Go to the store and buy milk'
    },
    {
      title: 'Create a Kanban app',
      description: 'Using Firebase and Angular create a Kanban app!'
    }
  ];
```

Or you can use an empty array []